# RAML inline application/xml example

Tags: web-services, mule, raml

```
 responses:
  200: 
    body: 
      application/xml: 
        example: |
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <my_response>
            <result>success</result>
            <message>great</message>
          </my_response>
```

Is this a valid inline application/xml body example for RAML endpoint definition? If not how should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is. 
Depending on what you want to do you may want to also specify the type using XSD. 
For example:

```
/jobs:
  displayName: Jobs
  post:
    description: Create a Job
    body:
      text/xml:
        type: |
          <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
                     elementFormDefault="qualified"
                     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="api-request">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element type="xs:string" name="input"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:schema>
```

Also there are some special keywords used for XML serialization: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#xml-serialization-of-type-instances